# How to add ItemTapped on ListView with аutomatic assignment of ID from SQLite using xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have a field to enter ID and a line read button.
When you write the ID and click the button, a message appears with the information on the corresponding line.
I want to remove the button "Read" аnd the input field so that when the user clicks the corresponding line, a message with the information from the line will be displayed ?

My xaml.cs code is:

```
async void ReadCity()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonId.Text))
        {
            //Get Person
            var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text));
            if (person != null)
            {
               
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Name: " + person.Name, "OK");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter PersonID", "OK");
        }
    }

    void BtnRead_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadCity();
    }
```

My xaml code is:

```
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Label Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="FAVORITES" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="txtPersonId" Placeholder="City ID for Delete"></Entry>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btnDelete" WidthRequest="200" Text="Delete" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked" />
                <Button x:Name="btnRead" WidthRequest="200" Text="Read" Clicked="BtnRead_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lstPersons">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding PersonID}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

Is there a way to remove the read button and get the ID relative to the pressed line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ListView "SelectionChanged" Event :

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
    SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
```

in your code behind :

```
        private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentSelection.Count != 0)
            {
                var bc = this.BindingContext as  YourViewModelName;
                // now you have bc.SelectedPerson and you can access it's properties
                // Display what ever you want 
                collection.SelectedItem = null; // if you want to clear selection
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two event will be triggered, "ItemTapped" and "ItemSelected", when user tap an item. The difference between them is that "ItemSelected" will only be triggered when the selection changed. If you want to click on the item to display the item info, "ItemTapped" is a better choice.

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
          ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
```

xaml.cs:

```
private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Tapped", "Person Name: " + (e.Item as Person).Name, "OK");
}

private async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Selected", "Person Name: " + (e.SelectedItem as Person).Name, "OK");
}
```